# Refering to a VBComponent by the worksheet codename

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the `VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule.InsterLines...` function.

However, the VBComponent wants to take the module name from the object explorer, not the name of the tab. Is there a way to find this for the `Activesheet`?

To clarify, in the picture below, if I use the use `VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeMo...`, it will print to the module labeled 1.  I would like it to print to the module named 2.

How can I find the module name associated to the sheet?

[image: Whats going on...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to find this for the activesheet?

Is this what you want?

```
Activesheet.Codename
```

Comment: That has to be some sort of a record response time- Champion
(Will accept in 11 mins)